# AirPlay display on Apple TV works but cursor can't go past half the screen

Tags: macos, appletv, airplay

I successfully mirrored my internal MacBook Pro display to a 3rd gen Apple TV. The resolution shifted as expected, audio in the connected TV works, video looks fine, but when I try to take the cursor past about 40% to the right I seem to hit an invisible wall.

This makes it impossible to put some videos full screen, as I can't reach the controls for this, and otherwise makes it awkward to operate stuff.

Is this something I should have known about, like a well-known limitation or a bug in macOS Sierra 10.12?

Comment: I have the same issue with a couple of MacBook Pros running 10.13. I haven't found a solution yet, but I'm hopeful one exists.

Comment: Thanks @Gray Loon. I'm not currently where the Apple TV is now, but I will investigate further next time I'm at it.

Comment: @GrayLoon, I found a discussion where it was suggestedto go to Display in System Preferences and make sure to choose "Best for Airplay display". I think I did that and it didn't help, but maybe something for you to try?
A restart was also suggested, I think I did that too, but I don't remember.